# Can "to" be reduced to "ə" in fast speech?

Tags: pronunciation

Many times in fast speech, i've heard people say the prep "to" like only with a sound /ə/ (maybe with a little flap t as in 'better'). For example: i'm trying to help. I'm not trying to get mad at....Or, Power to sing. In the sentence, i'm trying to help, it sounds like /am trai ə help/. Is that really what they do? 
  I ask this because i feel like it's smoother and easier for me to pronounce "to" with only a schwa sound when speak fast. I just wanna make sure it's proper.

PS: for instance, in this utube video https://youtu.be/tVja6oEUYlo, min 1:16. 'He helps people and corporations learn how to make better decisions'. That "to" is pronounced /ə/ or /də/ ?. it's fast, so i can't be sure,but I think it's /ə/

Comment: “... *wanna* make sure it's proper”? :)

Comment: @mari          it's common so i can use with confidence ^^

Comment: I hope you know that *ur*, *u*, *i* (but **I** would always capitalize it) *wanna*, and *gonna* may be fine in texts, YouTube comments and IMs but they are never "proper" in formal writing. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fast, informal, speech, yes, we often reduce *to* to a kind of ə, particularly in constructions like "going to", "want to", or anything "-ing to".  This is probably because enunciating the "-g t-" combination of sounds is a little slow and awkward.  In practice, "to" is often pronounced more like "tə" than like "t*oooo*".

In the video you linked to, I do hear the *t* of "to".  It's not particularly emphasized, but it is there.  Because *t* is a [stop consonant](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/Stop-Phonetics.htm), it's hard to emphasize it strongly, particularly when it comes next to a word boundary.

Also, I can't imagine anybody dropping the *n* sound from "trying" as in /am trai ə help/.  This may be because while you know that the word "to" has to be "to" because of its position in the sentence, regardless of exactly how it sounds, if you say "trai" for "trying", it sounds like you're just saying "try", which would be grammatically incorrect in "I'm try to help".

Comment: ur right. After i've read ur answer. i listened to the video again, with volume cranked up. I do hear the flap t in that 'to'. Normally, i turn volume to just enough to hear( i live with other people, don't want them to pay attention). That's why i missed it. And in your opinion, it should be /am trai-na help/, right? I trust u, 'cause ur a native speaker, i'm not. Thanks

Comment: Yes, /am trai-na help/ would be right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only in certain constructions. Specifically "Going to" and "Trying to" are often rendered as "gonna" and "tryna". Some linguists regard these two as new English words. It doesn't happen, as far as I know, even with similar constructions such as "wanting to" or "planning to".

Edit: but as J Sibeneichler point out, it does happen with "want to".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you heard was "am /traɪnə/ help". You sometimes see this contraction of *trying to* written as *tryna* or *trynna*. The same phenomenon is found in *wanna* (*want to*) and *gonna* (*going to*).